# How to split the stings displayed in single line

Tags: split, robotframework

Response from curl command returns the data as single line(given below). I would like to split the line by column name below to that put the value.

Currently it shows the output as

```
[ {
  "file" : "XXXX",
  "key" : "XYZ123456789",
  "previousSource" : "2017-05-23",
  "previousValue" : -1,
  "currentSource" : "2017-05-24",
  "currentValue" : -1
 }]
```

I want to save the output in the below format (psv format)

```
file|key|previousSource|previousValue|currentSource|currentValue|
XXXX|XYZ123456789|2017-05-23| -1|2017-05-24|-1
```

Please let me know the approach to convert into this format.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this with available robot keywords, or how to create a keyword in python to do this? Have you done any research to try to do this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using python built-in csv library.
Make a Helper.py file and add this code there.

```
import csv
def write_in_csv(filename, data, source='dict', write_mode='a'):
    len = get_csv_length(filename)
    with open(filename, write_mode) as csvfile:
        if source == 'list':
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        else:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=data.keys())
        if len == 0 and source == 'dict':
            writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Now in your robot file:

assuming ${response} has your curl response:

```
${response}=  Remove String  ${response}  {  [  }  ]  ${SPACE}  "
${response_list}  Split String  ${response}  :
${response_list_length}  Get Length  ${response_list}
${count}  Set Variable  ${0}
${response_dict}  Create Dictionary
:FOR  ${index}  IN RANGE  ${response_list_length}/2
\  Set to dictionary  ${response_dict}  ${response_list[${count}]}=${response_list[${count+1}]}
\  ${count}  Evaluate  ${count} + 2
write in csv  ${csv_file_path}  ${response_dict}
```